# SQL GROUP BY total price of every week of the year

Tags: sql, ms-access

OK, so i am doing some Access here and i cant figure it out, already tried a lot by searching but nothing really comes close. And i am hoping some of you knows what to do.

I have some tables on my database (just a simple one for school)

Table of products

```
Type    Price   Color  Height Model
--------------------------------------------
KL47    69      B      150    Dames Normal Model
VRS02   73      W      170    Heren Smal Model`
```

Table of copies - products

```
Copienr Type
------------------------
K664    KL47
T553    KL47
V3553   VRS02
V7744   VRS02
V9941   VRS02
```

Table of custumers

```
Customrnr   Companyname  Adress
-----------------------------------------
1           Jiver        Posthoorn 27
2           Veco         Weebosserweg 21
3           V&D          Omabakfietsjes 74
```

And at last a table for checking witch customer is renting witch product

```
Rentnr  Customernr  Copienr Date-from   Date-Till
-------------------------------------------------------
5       3           K664    11/5/2014   11/29/2014
6       3           T553    10/7/2014   12/13/2014
7       3           V3553   11/18/2014  12/19/2014
8       3           V3553   4/8/2015    8/12/2015
9       3           V7744   4/8/2015    7/8/2015
10      3           T553    5/4/2015    6/8/2015
```

Now I want a table of all products that company V&D rented for this year so far.
Group by total price of every week.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT t.typen, c.copienr, date-from, date-till, companyname, price
FROM typen t, copies c, rented-vieuw r, customers c
WHERE bedrijfsnaam = 'V&D'
AND c.customernr = r.customernr
AND r.copienr = c.copienr
AND c.type = t.type
AND date-from >= #1/1/2015#;
```

Further on, for grouping by total price for eatch week i tried a lot. Thinks that doenst even make any sence but I cant figure it out.
I hope you can help my out. Thanks!

Edit: The price in the table products is the cost for renting the product / weak***

Comment: I removed the mysql tag and changed "access" to "ms-access".

Comment: Ah oke, thanks for that! Sorry, pretty new in the IT (started school in feb)

Answer (score 0):

So here is my first attempt at an answer online,

My understanding of your questions is that you are trying to create a query with the products of single company for this year only. And get the total price for that product.

I assumed your price was a weekly price. I have added two columns to allow you to understand what I have done, a total days and total weeks. Also I have named your tables Products, Copiers - Products, Custumers and Renting based of the spelling and descriptions you gave

```
SELECT Renting.Rentnr, DateDiff("d",[Renting]![Date-from],[Renting]![Date-Till]) AS NumberDays, DateDiff("d",[Renting]![Date-from],[Renting]![Date-Till])/7 AS NumberWeeks, Custumers.Companyname, Products.Type, Products.Price, Renting.[Date-from], Renting.[Date-Till], Format([Products]![Price]*DateDiff("d",[Renting]![Date-from],[Renting]![Date-Till])/7,"Currency") AS Total
FROM Custumers INNER JOIN ((Products INNER JOIN [Copiers - Products] ON Products.Type = [Copiers - Products].Type) INNER JOIN Renting ON [Copiers - Products].Copienr = Renting.Copienr) ON Custumers.Customrnr = Renting.Customernr
WHERE (((Year([Renting]![Date-from]))=[Which year?]))
GROUP BY Renting.Rentnr, DateDiff("d",[Renting]![Date-from],[Renting]![Date-Till]), DateDiff("d",[Renting]![Date-from],[Renting]![Date-Till])/7, Custumers.Companyname, Products.Type, Products.Price, Renting.[Date-from], Renting.[Date-Till], Format([Products]![Price]*DateDiff("d",[Renting]![Date-from],[Renting]![Date-Till])/7,"Currency");
```

The WHERE statement is used to limit to the year you select you can change the `[Which year?]` to `Now()` to auto choose the current year, based of the computers system time/date.

Adding also `AND ((Custumers.Companyname)=[Which Company?]))` to the `WHERE` statement also allows the selection of a different company based on name of the company

Hard coding values like year and company means that there is only one option for your query and you need a new query for each year and company.

I hope I have hit the mark or close to it.

Edit:

I realise I didn't explain it all properly:
The `DateDiff(...` is used to get the difference between two dates, "d" is to say by days I could have also used "ww" to ask how many weeks between the dates, the next two fields are your date field.

All the joins were auto made because I linked all the tables in the relationship window. And this query was designed in the design view not using the SQL editor.

Comment: hmm, i am not sure or this wil work, i am triening to add this to my query.
Maybee i didnt explain it the right way, my excuse for that!

But I want a list of al de products company "V&D" rente in the past year (1/1/2015 till now). And then the total price for eatch weak the v&d rented some products. 

The price witch is given in the table is the price/ weak for renting.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a list of weeks of the dates from the first date to last date in question. Also, you will need the ISO year as this may differ from the calendar year.

First create a table `Number` with one field: `Number`. Make this the primary index.

Fill this with ten records from 0 to 9.

Then create a query `DateFirstLast`which will take a first and a last date as parameters:

```
PARAMETERS 
    DateFirst DateTime, 
    DateLast DateTime;
SELECT 
    DateAdd("d",[Hundred]![Number]*100+[Ten]![Number]*10+[One].[Number],[DateFirst]) AS [Date]
FROM 
    [Number] AS One, 
    [Number] AS Ten, 
    [Number] AS Hundred
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",[Hundred]![Number]*100+[Ten]![Number]*10+[One].[Number],[DateFirst])<=[DateLast];
```

Now, use this as source in a new query to create the ISO year-week numbers:

```
SELECT 
    DateFirstLast.Date, 
    ISO_WeekYearNumber([Date]) AS YearWeek
FROM 
    DateFirstLast;
```

This will list the dates and the year-week numbers for the dates.

For example, for 2012 it will be from `2011W52` to `2013W01`.

The function to calculate the week numbers:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekYearNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByRef intYear As Integer, _
  Optional ByRef bytWeek As Byte) _
  As String

' Calculates and returns year and week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' Optionally returns numeric year and week.
' 1998-2007, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53
  Const cbytMonthJanuary        As Byte = 1
  Const cbytMonthDecember       As Byte = 12
  Const cstrSeparatorYearWeek   As String = "W"

  Dim bytMonth                  As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  intYear = Year(datDate)
  bytMonth = Month(datDate)
  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(intYear, cbytMonthDecember, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000+ bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
  If bytMonth = cbytMonthJanuary Then
    If bytWeek >= cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear - 1 Then
      ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous year.
      intYear = intYear - 1
    End If
  ElseIf bytMonth = cbytMonthDecember Then
    If bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear Then
      ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next year.
      intYear = intYear + 1
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekYearNumber = CStr(intYear) & cstrSeparatorYearWeek & Format(bytWeek, "00")

End Function
```

The list of dates and weeks you can join with your sales data and apply the grouping you need.